# How to get answer from user Telegram Bot JS

Tags: javascript, node-telegram-bot-api

I'm `using node-telegram-bot-api`. My question - how create function like this (on screen)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTz42.png)

I'am using this code, but code working in definite ID user
How make to has been answer available everyone

```
// Create bot
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const bot = new TelegramBot('XXXXXXXX:AAEibBwftjTEKuYd9d2X0ACeyyzTk4DLe60', {
    polling: true
});

// List of id's we're waiting for
const wait = [];

// Hardcoded chat id
const chatId = 1234567;

// Ask and add to wait list
bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'What is your name?', { parse_mode: 'HTML' });
wait.push(chatId);

// On message
bot.on('message', (msg) => {

    // Check we're waiting on this user
    if (wait.includes(msg.chat.id)) {

        // Send reply
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Your name: ' + msg.text );

        // Remove from wait list
        wait.splice(wait.indexOf(msg.chat.id), 1);
    } else {

        // Normal message; notify user
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Hi! I\'m not expecting a reply from you! How can I help?');
    }
});
```